# SAS macro sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas, sas-macro

I want to store the columns of my table Tab1 in a macro variable, knowing that the library of my table TAB1 is temporary, moreover it is linked to a sql server DBMS database, I cannot store the columns using this request, you can help me plz:

```
%let colonnes = ;

proc sql noprint;
   select nliteral(name) into :colonnes separated by ","
   from dictionary.columns
   where libname = 'FA' and memname = 'Tab1';
quit;

%put &colonnes;
```

Comment: There will never by lowercase letters in the MEMNAME field of dictionary.columns.

Comment: I did that but it's the same because my base I think is not assigned

Comment: LIBNAME FA sqlsvr schema="dbo" datasrc=LOT
user=xxx pwd=xx ; run;

Comment: What do mean TAB1 is "temporary"?  Do you mean it is NOT a table in the DBO schema?  If it is not a table in the schema that the libref is pointing at then it will definitely not appear in DICTIONARY.COLUMNS.

Comment: temporary tables in a database are not stored in the dbo schema, they're often stored in your own schema. Is this T-SQL/MSFT SQL? Try connecting to the dB via explicit pass through and using the T-SQL dictionary tables which likely has access to the schema in question.

Comment: I solved the problem it was indeed a capital letter problem, thank you all

Comment: You can transfer a zero-row copy of the temp table to SAS to work with the SAS dictionary. `create table z as select * from connection to sqlsrv (select * from #temptable where 1=0)`

Answer (score 0):

How about do it like this:

```
%let dataset=FA.ta1;

data a;
  stop;
  set &dataset.;
run;

proc transpose data=a out=b(keep=_name_);
  var _all_;
run;


%let colonnes = ;

proc sql noprint;
   select _name_ into :colonnes separated by ","
   from b;
quit;

%put &colonnes;
```

?